# Deleted list is sticking around

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I've run into a bit of a weird scenario.

Using the SharePoint Management Shell I deleted a list and the command executed successfully.
However the list is still there when looking at the Lists collection on the SPWeb object.
When attempting to delete this list again I get the following error:

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

- Ensured the AllowDeletion flag when set to true for the list
- Set the AllowUnsafeUpdates flag to true on the Web object
- Run a Content Database Repair
- Dismounted and Mounted the content database

How I get rid of this list? Hoping you folks have some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [clear the SharePoint Configuration Cache](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/), and **run IISReset** in the SharePoint Management shell, then check again.

Comment: I tried this but no luck. There are five servers in this SharePoint Farm, I cleared the cache on all servers and then restarted IIS on all servers.